# Difference in NotesViewEntryCollection and NotesDocumentCollection

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I have gone through the documentation, Done some practices too on both the things.

but just want to get some clear working of both the term internally what actually it stores, when returned in a repeat control data.

Silly question but want some clean details on it.

Any kind of suggesion would be appretiated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NotesDocumentCollection, NotesViewEntryCollection, and NotesViewNavigator objects provide access to documents in a database.

Use a **NotesDocumentCollection** object if:

You want to act on a specific set of documents that meet certain criteria. 
There is no view in the database that contains every document you need to search. 
You do not need to navigate the documents' response hierarchies.

Views are a more efficient means of accessing documents because they are already indexed by the database itself. However, they do not necessarily provide access to the documents that you want. NotesViewEntryCollection and NotesViewNavigator objects provide access to view entries, which contain NotesViewEntry as well as NotesDocument information. NotesViewNavigator provides access to categories and totals as well as documents.

Usage of **ViewEntryCollections** :

ViewEntryCollections never contain categories or totals, only entries that correspond to documents. The methods and properties in NotesViewEntryCollection are the same as those for NotesDocumentCollection, except for IsSorted, because this property is always True for NotesViewEntryCollection.

Answer (score 4):

One is a collection of NotesViewEntry- Objects, the other a collection of NotesDocuments.

A view entry CAN contain a NotesDocument, but it does not have to (categories, totals...). 
View entries have special properties / methods (ColumnValues, Level, etc) that documents don't have.

A NotesViewEntryCollection is sorted as displayed in the view, a NotesDocumentCollection is UNSORTED.

For repeat controls: You deal with different objects that you have to treat differently to get values from them...

Comment: I always remember this thing: instead of: << a view entry contains notes documents >> , a better expression would be: << a view entry lists notes documents >>

Comment: This is -imho- not the correct wording. A view entry may list items of ONE notes document, but never multiple notes documents...

Comment: You are right. But I just highlighted the used verb: instead of <contains>, it will be more correct to say <lists>. A view lists items, and it not contains items

Answer (score 0):

> but just want to get some clear working of both the term internally what actually it stores

XPages cannot store Domino objects from one request to the next. A `ViewEntryCollection` can't store `ViewEntry` objects and a `DocumentCollection` can't store `Document` objects. All that *can* get stored is the values (Java data types, so dates are `java.util.Date`, not `DateTime`) you assign into components. So there's no difference in what gets stored.